# If $f$, $g$ are uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then $g \circ f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $h$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $\forall x,y \in dom(h)$, $|x - y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

My proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $g$ is uniformly continuous, $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $|x - y| < \delta$ implies $|g(x) - g(y)| < \epsilon$.

Now, $f$ uniformly continuous means that $\exists \delta' > 0$ s.t. $\forall x',y' \in \mathbb{R}$, $|x' - y'| < \delta'$ implies $|f(x') - f(y')|< \delta$.

So, for any $x', y' \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x' - y'| < \delta'$, we have $|f(x') - f(y')|< \delta$. Hence $|g(f(x')) - g(f(y'))| < \epsilon$. This is exactly what it means for $g \circ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be uniformly continuous, so we are done.

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Your proof is very incorrect, unfortunately. You've negated the definition of uniform continuity wrongly. There's also not a need to go by contradiction here.

Comment: @T.Bongers What is the correct negation?

Comment: Give it a shot and [edit] your question to include it. Start by writing (in quantifiers, if you please) what it *does* mean for a function $h$ to be uniformly continuous. A giant red flag here is that if $x = y$ then $|x - y| < \delta$ but $|g \circ f(x) - g \circ f(y)| = 0$ is not $\ge \epsilon$.

Comment: @T.Bongers I made these edits. How do they look? I am also working on a direct proof at the moment...

Comment: It looks better, but it's not a proof yet. You haven't yet used that $g$ or $f$ are uniformly continuous, for example. So why is it a problem that $f(x), f(y) \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @T.Bongers I just added a direct proof. It looks good to me, what do you think? And if I wanted to prove this by contradiction, what would it look like? Or is it even worth it?

Comment: Good job, you've got it. I don't see any easy contradiction proof that isn't substantially the same as what you've already done.

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks for your help! One more question: when stating what it means for $f$ to be unif. cont., is it okay to just choose any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$? Or is it necessary to choose $x', y' \in \mathbb{R}$? I think it's okay to do the former since we are choosing any two elements in the set of all reals, and it's really just a notational matter. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $g\circ f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R},$ one needs to prove that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R},$ if $|x-y|<\delta,$ then
$$|g(f(x)) - g(f(y))|<\varepsilon.$$

---

Now, fix $\varepsilon>0.$
Since $g$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R},$ there exists $\eta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R},$ if $|x-y|<\eta,$ then
$$|g(x) - g(y)|<\varepsilon.$$
Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R},$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R},$ if $|x-y|<\delta,$ then 
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\eta.$$

We claim that such $\delta>0$ will work. 
Indeed, fix $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-y|<\delta.$
By uniform continuity of $f$, we have
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\eta.$$
By uniformly continuity of $g,$ we have 
$$|gf(x))-gf(y))|<\varepsilon.$$
This concludes that $g\circ f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}.$